# How to recover removed pipeline in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, mongodb-compass

I accedentally removed pipeline, it had a lot more queries that took too much of my time. Is there any way to recover?

[image]

From Where I removed this pipeline? Here is the place:

I clicked on `Open Saved Pipelines` and then clicked on the remove icon ahead of that pipeline.
[image]

Comment: if you have not saved pipeline by clicking on save button (Save pipeline as..), I don't think it is possible to recover pipeline from compass.

Comment: @turivishal I had saved it that's why I could remove it.

Comment: I updated the question. I removed it from save pipeline menu.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to recover, but i would suggest you to ask this in [MongoDB community forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/new), probably mongodb developer will suggest.

Comment: @turivishal page not found

Comment: correct one [MongoDB community forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums).